# Can I recover a stack overflow account with a dead email address?

Tags: support, status-completed, user-accounts, merge-accounts

A while ago I tried to login to stack overflow, but I couldn't remember what email address I used when I registered. Now I've figured it out but the email address is dead, the domain no longer exists. Would it be possible to merge the accounts https://stackoverflow.com/users/22395/terence-simpson and https://stackoverflow.com/users/514830/terence-simpson ?

Comment: It's a registered account. Can you not log in to your OpenID provider?

Comment: @mmyers No, there is no OpenID associated with it

Answer (score 5):

Email your account information along with the old email address to team@stackoverflow.com so they can process your request.

Comment: I get an error when I try to change it: "Email is already registered"

Comment: @Terence: Shoot, then my lame attempt at a joke was wasted.  I'm afraid you'll have to email your account information along with the old email address to team@stackoverflow.com so they can process your request.  Sorry.

Comment: Thanks, I sent an email as you suggested and now the accounts are merged.